# I don't understand the meaning

Tags: meaning

The following is a quote from Joan of Arc. I don't understand the meaning of the last part, i.e., "blood will leave my body above the breast".

> Get up tomorrow early in the morning, and earlier than you did today,
>   and do the best that you can. Always stay near me, for tomorrow I will
>   have much to do and more than I ever had, and tomorrow blood will
>   leave my body above the breast.

Comment: I might think of that to be exsanguination.

Comment: Please make the title more descriptive of the specific issue you’re having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

"Blood will leave my body" means "I will bleed". It was a prediction, according to her bodyguard, [Jean d'Aulon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_d%27Aulon). She was indeed wounded by an arrow the following day between the neck and shoulder.